# Array reversal in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got 8 bytes Hex values in a cell as below which is in little endian format
00 00 08 04 22 00 40 00

With text split I could get individual hex values in an array.
= TEXTSPLIT(A1, , " ")

00
00
08
04
22
00
40
00

Is there an excel formula that I can use to grab the values in reverse order from an array to do below?

00
40
00
22
04
08
00
00

I don't want to use LEFT or MID or RIGHT extractors as I want to create generic formula that works on all data types.

Comment: use a combination of `INDEX()` and `SEQUENCE()` where the 'steps' of the SEQUENCE function are -1

Comment: What @DattelKlauber is thinking of is `=INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1, " "), 1, SEQUENCE(1, 8, 8, -1))` (and I admit it's much more elegant than my solution)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this very specific case you could use `=TRIM(CONCAT(MID(" "&A1,SEQUENCE(8,,22,-3),3)))` but to be more generic, try:

[image]

Formula in `A2`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,SORTBY(TEXTSPLIT(A1,," "),ROW(1:8),-1))
```

---

I suppose you can make this even more generic for any string you split on space:

```
 =LET(r,TEXTSPLIT(A1,," "),TEXTJOIN(" ",,SORTBY(r,SEQUENCE(ROWS(r)),-1)))
```

---

Note this is almost an exact copy of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74633427/9758194) question where you could also use the technique shown by @ScottCraner using `INDEX()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", ""), SEQUENCE(1, LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", ""))/2, LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", ""))-1, -2), 2)
```